# code keep firing like 7 times when using the for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script as I'm stored a list of elements in the arrays.

I have got a problem with running the code in the for loops.

When I try this:

```
program_X = list()
program_time = list()

for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
    program_X.append(position_start)
    program_length = minutes_length
    program_time.append(program_length)

program_X = map(str, program_X)
program_time = map(str, program_time)


#get the list of position_X for all buttons
for pos_X in program_X:

    #find the position with 375
    if pos_X == '375':
       print program_time
```

It will print the list of elements like 7 times which it supposed to be once:

```
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
16:16:57 T:6044  NOTICE: ['30', '150', '180', '60', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'...etc]
```

If I use `program_time` outside the `for pos_X` loop, it will print the list of elements only once without print like 7 times. I want to use `program_time` in the `for pos_X` so I can then start to work out the code for the time.

Can you please help me how I can use `program_time` in the `for pos_X` loop to print the list of elements only once without repeating like 7 times?

**EDIT: I can't get pass on if statement when I try this:**

```
#get the list of position_X for all buttons
for pos_X in set(program_X):

    #find the position with 375
    if pos_X == '375':
       program_lengths = program_time

       if program_lengths >= '30':
          print "hello 1"
          continue
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, but it's hard to test since [the code isn't a self contained example](http://sscce.org/). It might be easier for you to use a dict, since it seems like you are looking for a specific value?

Comment: yes it does, you can see that i'm running the loops twice and it make me to output 7 times, i only want to output like once. How I can do that?

Comment: We don't have the content of `programs` for example. If I were to try your code, python would complain that `programs` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `program_X` has more than one element with `375` value. Looking at the code it is definite that you print the `program_time` only when `pos_X` is equal to `375`. Also you need the output only once. So the best way to achieve it is using a `break` statement after `print program_time` instruction as:

```
for pos_X in program_X:

    #find the position with 375
    if pos_X == '375':
       print program_time
       break
```

Another way is to iterate over unique values of `program_X` using `set()` as:

```
for pos_X in set(program_X):

    #find the position with 375
    if pos_X == '375':
       print program_time
```

Looking at the EDIT of your post, I got a hint of what you are trying to achieve. Remove entire 2nd `for loop` of your code with below code. See if it helps, then I'll explain it to you:

```
prog_Xtime = dict(zip(program_X,program_time))
for pos_X in prog_Xtime:
    if pos_X == '375':
       if prog_Xtime[pos_X] >= '30':
          print "hello 1"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I can see it have fixed the issue, but I want to know how I can get pass on the if statement when I'm checking for the value using the variable `program_lengths`. When I try this: `program_lengths = program_time if program_lengths == '30': print "hello 1" break` it wont let me to get pass on the if statement. do you know why?

Comment: What do you mean by get pass on if statement. Do you want to continue iterating the loop. If that is the case use `continue` instead of `break`.

Comment: I have tried it but it wont let me to get pass on if statement. Please see the code in my update question.

Comment: `if program_lengths >= '30':` This statement always returns False because you are comparing a list `program_lengths` with a string `'30'`. So it will never print `hello 1`. Provide a proper explanation of what you are trying to do and I'll see if I can help...

Comment: sorry I mean this `if program_lengths == '30':` it is always return false because I'm comparing a list with a string that is return to true. I'm not sure why it is always return to false.

Comment: This will still return False always. Anyway I've uploaded replacement code for your 2nd for loop in the given code. Give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the entire context of your code snippet, but there are a few obvious problems:

```
for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
    program_X.append(position_start)
    program_length = minutes_length
    program_time.append(program_length)
```

iterates through `programs` (whatever that is) and then appends the *exact same* values to the lists `program_X` and `program_time` - because you're using the same variables (`position_start` and `minutes_length`) in every iteration. So if `position_start` is `375`, and `programs` has 7 items, then you'll get the same output 7 times.

Comment: what do you like to see the content of my code? you can see that i'm running the loops like twice which it make me to get the same output 7 times. How I can only get the output like 1 time?

Comment: Why are you running a loop at all? You're not changing anything inside the loop, so you'll get the same result every time.